# Controller undefined the unit test even after mocking

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a component test where I am mocking the controller for the component by using the angularjs's `$controllerProvider`. The injection is working fine but the controller context `this` is `undefined` even during the registration.

My component

```
import templateUrl from './pdf-export-modal.html.pug';
import './pdf-export-modal.less';

export default {
  templateUrl,
  bindings: {
    onClose: '&',
  },
  controller: 'PdfExportModalCtrl',
};
```

and the component test file

```
import angular from 'angular';

describe('component: pdf-export-modal', () => {
  let $rootScope;
  let $compile;
  let scope;
  let el;
  let html;
  let ctrl;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mainModule', ($controllerProvider) => {
    $controllerProvider.register('PdfExportModalCtrl', () => {
      ctrl = this;
      console.log(ctrl, this); // both are undefined here
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_) => {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    html = "<pdf-export-modal on-close='onClose'/>";
    scope.onClose = jasmine.createSpy('onClose');
    el = $compile(html)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
  }));

  describe('selecting compact', () => {
    // test
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the ES6 autobinding. The arrow function used `this` context from the test class [instead of creating a new one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) for `PdfModalCtrl`. Removed the arrow function and used ES5 syntax to make it work.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mainModule', ($controllerProvider) => {
  $controllerProvider.register('PdfExportModalCtrl', function () {
    ctrl = this;
    console.log(ctrl); //new context is created for the controller      
 });
}));
```